# HTML/CSS/JQUERY - Dropdown disappear when not hovering on menu

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm trying to create  a dropdown menu, which has ben going well so far.
I just came across 1 problem. When i'm not hovering on on the menu title, the dropdown disappears and so do the hover effect on the menu. 
my code might seem very messy, and a bit complicated. I apologize.

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/eeLfkqjy/6/
HTML:

```
<div id="navBar">
        <div id="logo">

        </div>
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="menuTitle_Container">
                <a class="menuTitle" href="index.html">HOME</a>
                <a class="menuTitle" href="sneakers.html">MENU 1</a>
                <a class="menuTitle" href="clothing.html">MENU 2</a>
                <a class="menuTitle" href="acessories.html">MENU 3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div id="dropdownMenu">
            <div id="dropdownMenu_SubmenuContainer">
                <div class="submenu_Container">
                    <div class="submenu_menuContainer">
                        <p class="clotheCategory">TITLE</p>
                            <a class="submenuTitle">MENU 1</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle">MENU 2</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle">MENU 3</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle">MENU 4</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle">MENU 5</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="submenu_menuContainer">
                        <p class="clotheCategory">TITLE</p>
                            <a class="submenuTitle">MENU 1</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle">MENU 2</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle">MENU 3</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle">MENU 4</a>
                    </div>
                </div>                
                <div class="submenu_Container">
                    <div class="submenu_menuContainer">
                        <p class="clotheCategory">TITLE</p>
                            <a class="submenuTitle">MENU 1</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle">MENU 2</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle">MENU 3</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="submenu_menuContainer">
                        <p class="clotheCategory">TITLE</p>
                            <a class="submenuTitle">MENU 1</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle">MENU 2</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle">MENU 3</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle">MENU 4</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle">MENU 5</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
 margin: 0; 
 background-color: green;
}
/* MENU */
#navBar {
    background-color: #464646;
    height: 65px;
    width: 100%; 
    display: -webkit-box;
}
#logo {
    width: 15%;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    height: 65px;
}
#menu {
    height: 65px;
    width: auto;
}
#menuTitle_Container{
    width: auto;
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
}
.menuTitle{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    line-height: 65px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: -webkit-block;
    display: block;
    transition: color 0.4s ease;
    transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
}
.menuTitle:nth-of-type(+n+2):hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: background-color 0.4s ease, color 0.4s ease;
    color: #353535;
}

/* DROPDOWN MENU  ON HOVER */

#dropdownMenu {
    width: 750px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-left: 20%;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
}
#mensmenu {
    height: 100;   
}
.submenu_Container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: none;
}
.submenu_menuContainer {
    width: 50%;
    height: 190px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 5%;
}
.submenu_menuContainer:nth-child(1) {
    border-right: 1px solid #B3B3B3;
}


.clotheCategory {
    font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #353535;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.submenuTitle {
    font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #353535;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: table;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menuTitle:nth-child(2)").hover(function () {
        $("#dropdownMenu").show();
        $("#dropdownMenu").stop().animate({opacity:'1'}, 400);
        $(".submenu_Container:nth-child(1)").css("display","flex");
    }, function() {
        $("#dropdownMenu").hide();
        $("#dropdownMenu").stop().animate({opacity:'0'}, 400);
        $(".submenu_Container:nth-child(1)").css("display","none");
});    
    $(".menuTitle:nth-child(3)").hover(function () {
        $("#dropdownMenu").show();
        $("#dropdownMenu").stop().animate({opacity:'1'}, 400);
        $(".submenu_Container:nth-child(2)").css("display","flex");
    }, function() {
        $("#dropdownMenu").hide();
        $("#dropdownMenu").stop().animate({opacity:'0'}, 400);
        $(".submenu_Container:nth-child(2)").css("display","none");
});    
});
```

Comment: Several elements have the same ID. This is unacceptable.

Comment: IDs need to be unique. You have multiple elements with the same ids throughout your markup

Comment: Yeah they have, should i change it to class's then?

Comment: @MagnusPilegaard yup you should. but you'll have to update all your CSS and javascript that reference this elements. (i.e. `#submenu_menuContainer` selectors would become `.submenu_menuContainer`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To easily fix your problem you would have to attach your `hover` event to both your menu item **and** your dropdown list. See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eeLfkqjy/4/).

Change this: `$(".menuTitle:nth-child(2)").hover(...` to this `$(".menuTitle:nth-child(2), #submenu_Container:nth-child(1)").hover(...`

But you have a real problem with all the IDs on your page. IDs need to be unique per page, classes can happen many times on a page.

This is making your jquery selectors very odd. `#submenu_Container:nth-child(2)`

But for simple hover's you should try looking into a pure CSS solution. But you may have to change some markup.

Comment: I changed all the ids. Thank you! I will try and test your code. :)

Comment: It's working well. Do you know how to keep the MenuTitle having its Hover effect, while hovering over dropdown menu?

Comment: @MagnusPilegaard You should change this CSS selector: `.menuTitle:nth-of-type(+n+2):hover ` to this `.menuTitle:hover, .menuTitle.active` which will fix your hover selector and create a CSS helper class called `active` which you can toggle in javascript. See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eeLfkqjy/7/)

Comment: AMAZING! Thank you! Just one last question though, when you move from menutitle to dropdown menu, there is a really fast effect where the color on  title menu text, switches from dark to white and back to black again. Any ideas on how to remove that?

Comment: @MagnusPilegaard See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eeLfkqjy/9/) for the fix in the javascript hover out event. The flicker happens because your submenu is not nested in your menu item... it's outside. So this produces a lot of problems and is why we recommend changing your menu structure to something that uses nested `<ul>`'s.

Comment: I know, i'm just so used to my complicated version, that it's kindof hard to change. Anyway, what did you change? Just the 2 lines in jQuery?

Comment: @MagnusPilegaard I added the `e` event object here: `}, function(e) {` and then added this if condition: `if(e.toElement.id !== 'submenu_Container')` above where it removes the `active` class from the menu item. It says: "If the element you are hovering too doesn't have the `submenu_Container` id then don't remove the active class."

Comment: I see. It's acting weird now. I added those lines, but still, have flashy effect ON my local site. The effect is gone in your fiddle though. Hmmm.

Comment: @MagnusPilegaard are you getting any javascript errors?

Comment: @MagnusPilegaard lol I just realize you said you changed all your IDs to classes. So that is probably why it is not working for you. You could change the if condition to something like this: `if(!$(e.toElement).hasClass('submenu_Container'))`

Comment: I already changed your snippetd from ID to class, but it still doesnt work besides on your fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I invite you to have a look on how to make this with CSS

https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-menus-with-more-forgiving-mouse-movement-paths/

Doing hovers with javascript could results that the hover won't trigger correctly on mobiles or tablets.

Here's a little menu I made in 2 min. http://jsfiddle.net/warface/ky413pnk/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="mainmenu">
    <li>Main Menu</li>
    <li>Menu 1
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>Submenu 1</li>
            <li>Submenu 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#mainmenu{ list-style:none;  background:#000; color:#fff}
#mainmenu li{display:inline-block; position:relative; padding:4px 10px; border-right:1px solid #fff}

.submenu{display:none; background:#000; color:#fff; position:absolute; top:26px; left:0}
#mainmenu li:hover ul{display:block; margin:0; padding:0}
#mainmenu li ul li{white-space:nowrap; padding:4px 10px}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to do with the HTML-Structure i have now?

Comment: Not sure, better use nester <ul> to achieve this. Since the parent <ul> will be hovered, when you mouse will be on the childrens, you'll still be in it's parent. So that's how the browser knows you are still hovering the main menu. Dunno if I'm clear

Comment: I've added a simple menu with submenu on hover with pure CSS. It's a rough made in 2min but I hope you can get the curve.

Comment: @MagnusPilegaard ya this nested `<ul>` approach to building your multi-level nav is very common and almost the standard. Keep your menus nested instead of outside in another div will allow you to use simple CSS `:hover` to get your menu to work. Then you can remove all that javascript (and yes you can animate fadein/fadeout with just CSS)